# A question about the definition of complete dg Lie algebras in a paper of Lazarev and Markl

Tags: model-categories, dg-lie-algebras, rational-homotopy-theory

In their paper [Disconnected Rational Homotopy Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1037), Lazarev and Markl give the following definition (page 23):

> **Definition:** A *complete differential graded Lie algebra* is an inverse limit of finite-dimensional, nilpotent differential graded Lie algebras (dgla).

The limit here is taken in the category of dglas, which is complete (and cocomplete). However, a couple of lines later, they show that complete dglas are pronilpotent assuming, apparently without loss of generality, that any complete dgla is a *sequential* limit of finite-dimensional nilpotent dglas, which I strongly believe is a more stringent condition that being an arbitrary limit. So what am I missing? Is the definition incorrect as stated (in the sense that we allow only some special kinds of limits), is the proof that complete dglas are pronilpotent wrong, or is there some implication or equivalence between various kinds of limits in the category of dglas that I don't know about?

In particular, I am interested to the model structure that they put on the category of complete dglas a bit later in the paper (page 36). We need the category to be complete and cocomplete, and if we can take arbitrary limits then completeness is obvious, while if we only allow e.g. sequential limits I'm not sure it holds.

I will be grateful for any contribution.

**Edit:** Cross-posted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/238152/44134).

Comment: I would suggest posting this to MathOverflow. This site is practically spammed with undergraduate questions, and the sheer volume means that most questions go unread. Your question seems to be of high-enough difficulty to warrant an Overflow post. Moreover, it'll stay on their "front page" much longer because they have fewer posts.

Comment: @FlybyNight Ok, thanks. I will leave it here for a bit anyway and then cross-post. You never know, someone maybe can help me out here too.

Comment: This site is devoted to questions ranging from undergraduate ones (excluding immediate homework) to "well-known" research questions, so I wouldn't systematically call the first "spam". But certainly this one belongs on MathOF.